# Buy games from Blizzard by USD

Tags: battle.net

I from Mongolia, which is EU region by Battle.net. When I see payment options I only see RUB there. But we don't use RUB (russian currency). So problem is, since i don't have RUB visa card, I only can pay USD. But if I change my region into US, price will become 39$, almost 4 times expensive than RUB payment option.

So my question is, can I put some USD in my card and purchase game from Blizzard which is price in RUB? They convert it?

EDITED/ADDED
When I use both EU, and US sites, prices are different.
https://eu.battle.net/shop/en/product/starcraft-ii-wings-of-liberty
https://us.battle.net/shop/en/product/starcraft-ii-wings-of-liberty

On EU its 499 RUB (14$), on US its 39.99$. Why price have this much difference? Don't you think everyone buy cheaper one from eu.battle.net? Also I wonder If I buy from EU.battle.net will they give me only Russians usable client?

Comment: I'm from the UK but if I use either my mastercard or visa to pay for items in non-uk currency (eg USD) then my card provider will do the exchange for me so I end up paying the approximate GBP equivalent. I would have thought that this was a common thing. Essentially in my experience a card is not tied to a particular currency though that may be related to the financial institution that is backing it. So perhaps check your card providers website for this kind of info.

Comment: Forgive me if I am wrong but can't you use paypal? Paypal does change it.

Comment: There aren't Paypal option.

Comment: Also my Visa card only can use USD.

Comment: The copy of Starcraft sold in Russia is significantly different then the one you buy outside of Russia.  If I am not mistaken you have purchase access time to make up for the difference in price.  Starcraft II is a global game, you can play on any region, provide you purchase the full client.  Please verify what your $14 is actually purchasing because there is no way your getting the full game for that price.

Comment: @GereltOd Aha sorry my bad.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can buy the game with your USD card even if it is priced in rubles. The fee will be based on the exchange rate for the two currencies.

Comment: there is 1 problem. if i see it from https://eu.battle.net it says 499 rub (14$), if I see it from https://us.battle.net it says 39.99$. So much difference in price. Since I can buy both of these sites, I wonder what if they give me only Russians usable (region locked) client?

Comment: @GereltOd you should put that in your question (and if you do, mention which game you're talking about).

Comment: Sorry, Starcraft 2 Wings of Liberty.